# How do ETFs like SPY/VOO handle Rebalance events?

Tags: etf, rebalancing, event-study

When TSLA got added to the SP 500 Index, SPY, VOO, and others must-have gone ahead and bought the stock.

My question is, about the process they use? Do they outsource to Banks? Do they buy it slowly prior to rebalancing themselves? How are Creation/Redemption baskets affected? any info/links would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I know the history, but am a speculating a little on the current.

Way back, a special create/redeem basket was issued that was "but $50M Tesla, sell ".  In other words there were non-matching create and redeem baskets.  An AP (Authorized Participant, the big investment/trading banks) would "help out" by executing both sides of this.  That party was known by the unfortunate term "a friendly redeemer'.

There are reasons that contrived create/redeem became a bit less popular.
However, recall that every ETF is also a mutual fund.  So, it can trade like a mutual fund.  The fund manager simply sells \$50M of the stock leaving, and buys \$50M of Tesla, if needed.

Comment: The strange part is, that in this case TSLA getting added. Both the creation and redemption baskets we the same, they suddenly had TSLA show up one day with the other name out. I doubt that it was all bought on a single day. Same thing for SPY/IVV/VOO

Comment: The basket is "right" as of its publication day.  The manager could easily have spent 2 weeks selling the exiting stock and buying Tesla, letting everyone know on a certain date that new creates/redeems have Tesla, and not the stock that got sold.  Will there be a mismatch between the fund and the basket duirng that accumulation period?  Yes, but it's not a huge error and gets traded out.